# Did "npm install" become deterministic in npm 7?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-ci

Here https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/
it's said:

> The lockfile v2 unlocks the ability to do deterministic and reproducible builds to produce a package tree.

But I wonder is it the default behavior now for npm 7? That is, if there is a `package-lock.json` will `npm install` update top-most packages with imprecise versions like `^1.0.0` from `package.json` or it will always work the same way as `yarn` does?

If `npm install` is deterministic now, will I be right if I say that `npm ci` is mostly an equivalent of

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

with some additional checks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Yes!

**Longer Answer:**

Provided you have a `package-lock.json` or a `yarn.lock` file, both `npm` or `yarn`, respectively, do yield deterministic results.

One thing to note here is that yarn, using yarn.lock file, however, yields deterministic builds only for a specific version of yarn.

> Yarn installs are guaranteed to be deterministic given a single
> combination of yarn.lock and Yarn version. It is possible that a different version of Yarn will result in a different tree layout on disk.

Whereas npm's algorithms allow it to yield deterministic results even for different versions of the npm because npm tree building contract is entirely specified by the package-lock.json file.

You can find a more detailed explanation of the two in this [Blog](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson.html)